# Avoiding fragmenting of text extracted from PDF after processing with Ghostscript

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

After processing with Ghostscript, I sometimes see whitespace breaking up the words as seen with pdftotext or in a PDF viewer when searching or selecting.  Possibly unrelated but the anomalies seem to correspond with kerning variations in the rendered font.

Is there a way to avoid this?

For example, from GS 9.23 (also occurred with earlier versions):

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
   -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dPARANOIDSAFER -dBATCH \
   -sOutputFile=./output.pdf input.pdf
```

Excerpt from `pdftotext input.pdf`:

```
Review this manual before
operating deep cleaner
```

while `pdftotext output.pdf`:

```
Re vie w t his m a nua l be fore
ope ra t ing de e p c le a ne r
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ghostscript and the pdfwrite device (as explained in VectorDevices.htm) does not simply 'fiddle' with the input when producing a PDF file. The input (from whatever source; PDF, PostScript, XPS, PCL, PCL-XL) is fully interpreted into marking operations, those marking operations are sent to the device which turns them back into PDF constructs.

So the low level (PDF) format describing the page need not bear any relation to the low level format of the input. In particular you cannot expect the PDF operations in the input to be reflected in the output.

The visual appearance will be the same (or should be, because that's the main goal), but the actual operations won't be.

The reason for the difference in the text output is because, basically, there is no 'metadata' in a PDF file that describes words, paragraphs, columns etc. When you extract text from a PDF file what you actually get is a series of character codes and positions.

Its up to the text extraction code to try and make some sense of that. I'd guess that pdftotext is using the rather naive approach of assuming that text strings are words.

This is problematic because there are numerous different ways to handle kerning, justification and other spacings in PDF. You could do something like :

```
(Te) Tj
10 0 Td
(st) Tj
```

Or :

```
[(Te) 2 (st)] TJ
```

The pdfwrite device doesn't know what the original was, so what it emits could be either of those, depending on some heuristics. The chances of it matching the original are low.

I suspect that pdftotext would regard the first operation as "Te st" and the second operation as "Test"

One possible solution would be to use Ghostscript's txtwrite device to extract the text, it **might** do a better job.

As with your other question, it would be best to supply examples when asking these kinds of questions, because without that its pretty much guesswork.

TL;DR

> Is there a way to avoid this?

No.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Since being able to preserve as much text as possible using stock pdf viewers was vital, I ended up turning to a different tool in this case.  The clarity and depth of your response was very helpful.